# Pass a list from api function to another function in flask

Tags: python, api, flask

**need to transfer the list from one api function to another**

> ```
> @app.route('/get_output',methods = ['GET','POST'])
> def input_function():
>     list=['1','2','3','4']
>     status='success'
>     length=4
>     return (jsonify({'list':list,'status':status,'length'}))
> ```

```
  @app.route('/get_part',methods=['GET']
  def part_function():
      "" I need list to be get print here from the above function""
```

Comment: What do you mean by   "" I need list to be get print here from the above function""? Are you trying to print "list=['1','2','3','4']" at /get_part that was, I suppose,  previously saved by a post at /get_output? If you so, you might need to store that value so some space of shared memory (DB, or a variable that is located in the app scope, instead of the function scope).

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` in your first function is not valid - I speculate that it should be something like:

```
{'list':list,'status':status,'length': length}
```

You also want to avoid using `list` in a variable name since it's a python built-in.

What I would do is use the `redirect` function.
Since you cannot pass a `list` or `dict` object to another endpoint, the only option is a string. In `part_function` you would need to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it back to a `dict`:

```
import ast
```

The `part_function` endpoint:

```
@app.route('/get_part/<myList>', methods=['GET'])
def part_function(myList):
    myList = ast.literal_eval(myList)
    print(myList)
    return jsonify(myList)
```

and `list_output`:

```
@app.route('/get_output', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def input_function():
    list_ = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    status = 'success'
    length = 4
    return redirect(url_for(".part_function", myList={'list': list_, 'status': status, 'length': length}))
```

It should print:

```
{'list': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'status': 'success', 'length': 4}
```

Also remember to import `redirect` and `url_for` from Flask